# Generic zooming child views in android

Tags: android, performance, zooming, scale

I have a custom viewgroup that should contain a lot of direct child views that should be touchable. So I need zooming that zooms the whole view not just drawable parts.

I tried to implement my own solution. Where I call requestLayout in onScale callback and then modify child layout.

```
@Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        int count = getChildCount();


        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            final View child = getChildAt(i);

            float x = DeviceDimensionsHelper.convertDpToPixel(SchemeConstants.OFFSET.getValue()*10, getContext());
            float y = DeviceDimensionsHelper.convertDpToPixel(SchemeConstants.OFFSET.getValue()*6, getContext());

            x = ((x - mScaleGestureDetector.getFocusX())*mScaleFactor)+mScaleGestureDetector.getFocusX();
            y = ((y - mScaleGestureDetector.getFocusY())*mScaleFactor)+mScaleGestureDetector.getFocusY();

            if (child.getVisibility() != GONE){
                child.layout(
                        Math.round(x),
                        Math.round(y),
                        Math.round(x + child.getMeasuredWidth()*mScaleFactor),
                        Math.round(y + child.getMeasuredHeight()*mScaleFactor)
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

And this works only child views flicker a little when zooming (little but they still do). Notice everything should scale around the pivot point between 2 fingers when pinch zooming.

I tried another solution with setScaleX, setScaleY and setPivotX, setPivotY but that solution flickers a lot more (still works though).

I saw some solutions on stackoverflow with matrices but those solutions were pretty localized (to me at least) and as soon as I try anything with child.getMatrix.anything I get crashes and exceptions in logcat. Some solutions were also made for older android versions so I figure I there could be newer alternative.

Is there a mid-painful solution to zooming child views from viewgroup (without flickering)?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't found an answer yet try out this.
https://github.com/Xjasz/AndroidZoomableViewGroup

I spent hours getting this to work.
I hope it saves others the headache.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the end the solution above worked fine, my eyes were so much in debug mode that anything seemed like a bug :) .. Transformations can get a bit messy depending on what you're trying to accomplish.